# Has angular been replaced with typescript?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

So I went through a good tutorial of Angular 1.x. 
I visited angular.io to have a look at Angular 2. 
All I can see is Typescript, Javascript, and Dart references. 
Is what I learnt about Angular pointless now and should I start learning Typescript?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing you ever learn is pointless...

Comment: AngularJS is a frontend framework written in Javascript. `Typescript`, developed by Microsoft, is another structure or paradigm to write Javascript and it is compiled to Javascript. Hope this clears.

Comment: @mparnisari haha well that's a nice thing to hear :).

Comment: @PrateekGupta Are there still references to angular on angular.io then?Like if you go to angular.io and go to "quickstart", Is that code Angular 2 or Typescript?

Comment: Angular 2 is written in TypeScript. TypeScript is just the language used for programming the framework. However it transpiles to Javascript in the end.

Comment: @user1956779 You can choose your choice of language there from a dropdown menu. Goto this page https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html it has the same quickstart with JS examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is TypeScript, new language or a framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716390/what-is-typescript-new-language-or-a-framework)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is only a superset of Javascript. So everything you can do in JS, you can automatically do with TypeScript, too.

With Angular 2 the whole framework changed. Things that partially stayed similar is the template rendering, where only a few keywords changed their name, but the overall concept stayed the same.

The approach for building the app however changed completely.

[I'd suggest this article.](https://dzone.com/articles/typed-front-end-with-angular-2) Be careful though, since a few things stated on that page are already outdated again.

Comment: Is it worth learning? Or sticking with Angular 1.x? Or something else?

Comment: IMO it is not worth investing any new development in Angular 1.x. Personally I migrated all my apps from Angular 1.x to 2 (with considerable effort)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, of course you should start learning **Angular2** with **Typescript**(or any other available platform).

***Angular2 framework has been written from the scratch in Typescript.***

Believe me by far its one of the best frameworks available nowadays.**It provides many features**(You'll come to know once you start learning it). Testing components has become so easy.

You can use ***javascript, dart & typescript*** with **Angular2**.
 I prefer to use **Typescript** with **Angular2**.
 Compare to Javascript, typescript is easy and helpful. *There is a separate process which converts your typescript code to javascript code*.

while coming from **Angular1.x(with JS)** background, I understand it is not easy as **Angular2.0** is not directly related to **Angular1.x**.

But soon **Angular1.x** will be replaced by **Angular2.0** and then you will have to learn it so better to start learning now.

**Additionally**, you can migrate your **Angular1.x** apps to **Angular2.0** with [upgrade process](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)

I have so many things to say but I think this much will help to go ahead.